# Copy first six characters of filenames and amend it as the top line of the same .txt files

Tags: macos

I have a dir/folder of .txt files and I'd like to grab the first six characters of each .txt file filename and paste it into the beginning of each, same .txt file (followed by a TAB).

Filename example:

- 123456 Something Awesome.txt
- 234567 Another Awesome Thing.txt

So "123456 Something Awesome.txt" would begin with "123456[TAB]" and so on.

I'm doing this as part of a batch (.bat) on a Mac.

(I'll be importing the .txt files into Excel so the first 6 chars/numbers of the filename would essentially become the first data cell for each file/line of data - which is also why I need the TAB, so that the rest of the file will fill the following cells.)

Thanks!

Comment: Mac doesn't use `.bat` files, that's a Windows thing. Also please show what you've attempted.

Comment: You took the [tour], did you read [ask], and [mcve]?

Comment: .bat does work on Mac. It's run through Mac's Terminal.app. What I have used for this specific process has failed, so iI thought it worthless for me to post sample code.

Comment: Mac OSX and higher will run .bat files - https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110818171632AA4szz5&guccounter=1 (you *can* end it in ".bat" - I've been running one for weeks).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could probably work. Put your *.txt files in a directory and create file `myscript.sh`. Execute `chmod +x myscript.sh` in the same directory so you are able to execute your shell script. Put the following code into you shell script and execute it with `./myscript.sh` in your directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ./*.txt; do
    text="${filename:2:6}"
    echo $text | cat - $filename > temp && mv temp $filename
done
```

Thats a basic construction, just insert an additional `tab` and you are good to go.

Comment: That yields a lot of "no such file or directory" errors, but that may be because the file names have paces(?). The results come out like:

cat: 123456: No such file or directory 
cat: Something: No such file or directory
cat: Awesome.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: ...has SPACES :)

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: How can I get it to disregard blank spaces in the filename(s)? Looks like that is the issue :) Also, it's adding a line return after the 6 chars (when I need a tab).

Comment: My "fix" for removing the spaces was to copy the files to a new dir, replace the spaces with underscores and then run the process above on those files. Then it worked :)